# DocuSign Connect - Creating a Listener

Tags: docusignapi

**DocuSign** Connect Guide states that when creating a listener, for the method name `DocuSignConnectUpdate`, you need one parameter type `DocuSignEnvelopeInformation`.

Only problem is on their `DocuSign.eSign` namespace, there is no `DocuSignEnvelopeInformation` class to be found.

Is the guide out of date or am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please upvote all useful answers, including those to questions by other people. And please "check" (accept) the best answer to your own questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The part of the Connect Guide you're quoting only applies if you configure your webhook (Connect) subscription to use SOAP message transmission format. (Which I advise against.)

If you choose to use SOAP message transmission format, your listener needs to be a SOAP server that will process incoming SOAP requests to method `DocuSignConnectUpdate` with parameter `DocuSignEnvelopeInformation`

In this case, **your** app is **receiving** the SOAP requests, not requesting them, as is more usual when using SOAP. Because your listener is receiving the SOAP requests to `DocuSignConnectUpdate`, it does not appear in the DocuSign Signature SOAP WSDL file that you reference. That WSDL file and name space describe the methods that your app **requests**.

Rather than setting up a SOAP listener, it is usually easier to set up a plain HTTPS listener (server) to receive and process the incoming webhook messages.

Comment: Larry, I appreciate your help.  So if I create a simple HTTP Listener, will the webhook POST still be looking for the DocuSignConnectUpdate webmethod name? And, what parameter should I include in that webmethod to receive the xml body of the POST message?

Comment: The incoming webhook POST call from the DocuSign platform will be a POST to the url that you specify in your Connect Configuration. (You configure your Connect configuration either via the control panel or via an API call.) If you enter url http:testserver.example.com/docusign_listener then that's the URL that DocuSIgn will call. Or you could use http:testserver.example.com/docusign_listener.aspx if you want. Your choice.